A compilation error while using builtin func "max" with Go 1.22.1 : "invalid operation: invalid use of ... with built-in max"
I want to use max to get the maximum in slice, and I looked at the function declaration for max:
func max[T cmp.Ordered](x T, y ...T) T
But even though it was the same as my "myMax" declaration, it reported a compilation error, which confused me.
This is my code:
package main

import (
    "cmp"
    "fmt"
)

func maxSubArray(nums []int) int {
    dp := make([]int, len(nums))
    dp[0] = nums[0]
    for i := 1; i < len(nums); i++ {
        dp[i] = max(dp[i-1]+nums[i], nums[i])
    }
    return myMax(dp[0], dp[1:]...) // all going well
    //return max(dp[0], dp[1:]...) // compilation error:invalid operation: invalid use of ... with built-in max
}

func myMax[T cmp.Ordered](a T, b ...T) T {
    res := a
    for _, v := range b {
        if v > res {
            res = v
        }
    }
    return res
}

func main() {
    nums := []int{-2, 1, -3, 4, -1, 2, 1, -5, 4}
    s := maxSubArray(nums)
    fmt.Println(s)
}


As my code writes, I wrote myMax with the same signature instead, and it worked fine.
I knew that if I passed a slice as a variable, it would be used without generating a new slice, so I thought it would work fine with max, but it failed to compile.
Of course I also know that slice is not comparable (except to nil).
// Sorry about my English.

From the documentation (emphasis added):

The max built-in function returns the largest value of a fixed number of arguments of cmp.Ordered types.

max does not support the ... operator. Note that max is not a normal function, but a built-in function. This is a fundamental difference between max and myMax. The general rules for functions do not apply to built-in functions.
For slices, use the slices.Max function instead of the built-in function.
